# Does topological sense of continuity work only for invertible functions?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and let $ f: X \to Y$ be a function. $f$ is called continous if and only if for every open $U \subset Y$, the set $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. [source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/General_Topology/Continuity)

I've heard that the above is a generalization of the continuity in terms of epsilons and deltas, and, I understand why it is said so. In the context of functions mapping reals to reals, if both input set and output set are equipped with standard topology, we can see that the openness condition is the epsilon delta condition.

My question is does this generalization only works for **invertible functions**?. Since, in the definition itself we talk about $f^{-1}$.

Comment: That notation does not refer to the functional inverse of $f$ (which, as you say, might not exist), but rather the inverse image of a set under $f$.

Comment: @Joe, how about making your comment an answer, and filling it out a little...? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any function $f : A \to B$, invertible or not, we define this notation: for a set $E \subseteq B$,
$$
f^{-1}(E) = \{a \in A : f(a) \in E\} .
$$

---

Example:  Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the function $f(a) = a^2$.  Then $f$ is not invertible, but
$$
f^{-1}([1,2]) = [-\sqrt2,-1]\cup [1,\sqrt2\,] ,
$$
the set of all numbers whose square is in the interval $[1,2]$.

---

To prove that this function $f$ is continuous, we need: for any open set $U \subseteq \mathbb R$, then set $f^{-1}(U)$ is also open.  For example, the set $V:= (1,+\infty)$ is open, so we must conclude that $f^{-1}(V)$ is also an open set.  That is true since
$$
f^{-1}(V) = (-\infty,-1) \cup (1,+\infty)
$$
is an open set.  This must be true for **all** open sets $U \subseteq \mathbb R$.

Comment: Now when you talk about openness, which of the set in the union should be open? Should both be? i.e: [-sqrt(2),1] or [1, sqrt(2)]

Comment: The set $f^{-1}(U)$ should be an open set.  Apply the definition of "open set".